# Reading long data structure in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have to read a data structure from a text file (space separated), one data item per line. My first tentative would be

```
data Person = Person {name :: String, surname :: String, age :: Int, ... dozens of other fields} deriving (Show,...)

main = do
  string <- readFile "filename.txt"
  let people = readPeople string
  do_something people

readPeople s = map (readPerson.words) (lines s)

readPerson row = Person (read(row!!0)) (read(row!!1)) (read(row!!2)) (read(row!!3)) ... (read(row!!dozens))
```

This code works, but the code for `readPerson` is terrible: I have to copy-paste the `read(row!!n))` for all fields in my data structure!

So, as a second attempt, I think that I might exploit Currying of the `Person` function, and pass it the arguments one at the time.

Uhm, there must be something in Hoogle, but I cannot figure out the type signature ... Never mind, it looks simple enough and I can write it myself:

```
readPerson row = readFields Person row

readFields f [x] = (f x)
readFields f (x:xs) = readFields (f (read x)) xs
```

Ahh, looks much better coding style!

But, it does not compile! `Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: t ~ String -> t`

Indeed, the function `f` I am passing to `readFields` has a different type signature in each invocation; that's why I could not figure its type signature ...

So, my question is: what is the simplest and elegant way to read a data structure with many fields?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38271220/constructing-haskell-data-types-with-many-fields

Comment: Do `Person` have fields with different types? If so there probably isn't a really simple way to fix this problem...

Answer (score 3):

First, it's always a good practice to include types for all top-level declaration. It makes code better structured and much more readable.

One simple way how to achieve this is to take advantage of [applicative functors](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Applicative_functors). During parsing, you have an "effectful" computation where the effect is consuming part of the input and its result is one parsed piece. We can use the `State` monad to track the remaining input, and create a polymorphic function that consumes one element of the input and `read`s it:

```
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad.State

data Person = Person { name :: String, surname :: String, age :: Int }
    deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, Read)

readField :: (Read a) => State [String] a
readField = state $ \(x : xs) -> (read x, xs)
```

And in order to parse many such fields we use the `<$>` and `<*>` combinators which allow to sequence operations as follows:

```
readPerson :: [String] -> Person
readPerson = evalState $ Person <$> readField <*> readField <*> readField
```

Expression `Person <$> ...` is of type `State [String] Person` and we run `evalState` on given input to run the stateful computation and extract the output. We still need to have the same number of `readField` as many times as there are fields, but without having to use indices or explicit types.

For a real program you'd probably include some error handling, as `read` fails with an exception, as well as the patterm `(x : xs)` if the input list is too short. Using a full-fledged parser such as [parsec](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec) or [attoparsec](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec) allows you to use the same notation and to have proper error handling, customize parsing of individual fields etc.

---

Even more universal way is to automate wrapping and unwrapping fields into lists using [generics](https://wiki.haskell.org/Generics). Then you just derive `Generic`. If you're interested, I can give an example.

Or, you could use an existing serialization package, either a binary one like *cereal* or *binary*, or a text-based one such as *aeson* or *yaml*, which usually allow you to do both (either automatically derive (de)serialization from `Generic` or provide your custom one).

Comment: I'd strongly recommend considering standard approaches like cereal / binary / aeson / yaml.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Simpler solution if you are reading from strings:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

data Person = Person { name :: String, age :: Int, height :: Double }
    deriving Show

class Person' a where
    person :: a -> [String] -> Maybe Person

instance Person' Person where
    person c [] = Just c
    person _ _  = Nothing

instance (Read a, Person' b) => Person' (a -> b) where
    person f (x:xs) = person (f $ read x) xs
    person _ _      = Nothing

instance {-# OVERLAPPING #-} Person' a => Person' (String -> a) where
    person f (x:xs) = person (f x) xs
    person _ _      = Nothing
```

then, if the list is of the right size you get:

```
\> person Person $ words "John 42 6.05"
Just (Person {name = "John", age = 42, height = 6.05})
```

and if not you get nothing:

```
\> person Person $ words "John 42"
Nothing
```

---

[Constructing Haskell data types with many fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38271220/constructing-haskell-data-types-with-many-fields/38272395#38272395) provides a solution when all the record fields are of the same type. If they are not, a slightly more polymorphic solution would be:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, CPP #-}

data Person = Person { name :: String, age :: Int, height :: Double }
    deriving Show

data Val = IVal Int | DVal Double | SVal String

class Person' a where
    person :: a -> [Val] -> Maybe Person

instance Person' Person where
    person c [] = Just c
    person _ _  = Nothing

#define PERSON(t, n)                                \
instance (Person' a) => Person' (t -> a) where {    \
    person f ((n i):xs) = person (f i) xs;          \
    person _ _ = Nothing; }                         \

PERSON(Int,    IVal)
PERSON(Double, DVal)
PERSON(String, SVal)
```

then,

```
\> person Person [SVal "John", IVal 42, DVal 6.05]
Just (Person {name = "John", age = 42, height = 6.05})
```

In order to construct `Val` types, you may create another type-class and make the desired instances:

```
class Cast a where
    cast :: a -> Val

instance Cast Int    where cast = IVal
instance Cast Double where cast = DVal
instance Cast String where cast = SVal
```

then, it would be slightly simpler notation:

```
\> person Person [cast "John", cast (42 :: Int), cast 6.05]
Just (Person {name = "John", age = 42, height = 6.05})
```